# Maybe a simple array issue

Tags: php

I'm having a bit of a problem here. I've checked soo many times for errors and all but I can't get this to work. So I have to create a program which reads 3 lines of input. It's about a grocery shop which has 2 different price values during the week and the weekend. I have to make it output only the price for the fruit * the quantity and if the day or the fruit does not exist output "error". I'm really confused why my code is not working. I've only started PHP, so maybe I just don't have much experience.

```
$type = strtolower(readline());
$day = strtolower(readline());
$quantity = floatval(readline());
$days = array("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday");
$weekend = array("saturday", "sunday");
$fruit_normal = array(
    "2.50" => "banana",
    "1.20" => "apple",
    "0.85" => "orange",
    "1.45" => "grapefruit",
    "2.70" => "kiwi",
    "5.50" => "pineapple",
    "3.85" => "grapes"
);
$fruit_we = array(
    "2.70" => "banana",
    "1.25" => "apple",
    "0.90" => "orange",
    "1.60" => "grapefruit",
    "3.00" => "kiwi",
    "5.60" => "pineapple",
    "4.20" => "grapes"
);
$search = array_search($day, $days);
$search1 = array_search($day, $weekend);
$search2 = array_search($type, $fruit_normal);
$search3 = array_search($type, $fruit_we);
if ($search != NULL && $search2 != NULL) {
    $price = $search2 * $quantity;
    $formatted = number_format($price, 2);
    print $formatted;
} elseif ($search1 != NULL && $search3 != NULL) {
    $price = $search3 * $quantity;
    $formatted = number_format($price, 2);
    print $formatted;
} elseif ($search == NULL && $search1 == NULL && $search2 == NULL && $search3 == NULL) {
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what do you mean exactly? Do you get an exception, does it not do what you expect, does it not do anything at all, etc.? Have you tried using `var_dump()` on your `$search` variables to find out what they are and which `if` statement your code should end up in?

Comment: array_search evaluates weirdly, Warning
This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions I'll try them our right now.And when I type in all the info the code just exits withouth throwing any exception or displaying any output

Comment: That could be because it's not reaching any of your `if` conditions, or because there's a relevant warning/error somewhere and you have your `error_reporting` level set too low so you don't see it. Simplest check is to just add an `else { echo "something else happened"; }` at the end to see if your code ends up there

Comment: I'm back with some progress `var_dump` showed that `$search` returns false.But why it does?Is it because `$weekend` array has only 2 items in it?

Comment: What is the value of `$day`?

Comment: It's a random day from the week and sometimes `$search` on days or days from the weekend returns `FALSE` sometimes `NULL` prbably this can be solved by using the `||` operetor so i'm going to test it out

Comment: What I meant was, when `$search` is `false`, what is the actual value of `$day` at that time? Is it actually something that's in the array?

Answer (score 0):

So that's how i solved my problem first i made all of arrays consisting of parameter only to start from 1. And then replaced all of the `NULL` values to `FALSE` when checking for result from `array_search`I'm still not sure what was the real problem but for now I'll accept that's how it is.

```
$type = strtolower(readline());
$day = strtolower(readline());
$quantity = floatval(readline());    
$days = array(1 => "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday");
$weekend = array(1 =>"saturday", "sunday");   
$fruit_normal = array(
    "2.50" => "banana",
    "1.20" => "apple",
    "0.85" => "orange",
    "1.45" => "grapefruit",
    "2.70" => "kiwi",
    "5.50" => "pineapple",
    "3.85" => "grapes"
   );
    $fruit_we = array(
    "2.70" => "banana",
    "1.25" => "apple",
    "0.90" => "orange",
    "1.60" => "grapefruit",
    "3.00" => "kiwi",
    "5.60" => "pineapple",
    "4.20" => "grapes"
    );    
$search = array_search($day, $weekend);
$search1 = array_search($type, $fruit_normal);
$search2 = array_search($type, $fruit_we);
$search3 = array_search($day, $days);    
if($search1!= FALSE && $search3 != FALSE ){
    $price = $search1 * $quantity;
    echo number_format($price, 2); 
}elseif($search != FALSE && $search2 != FALSE){
    $price = $search2 * $quantity;
    echo number_format($price, 2);
}elseif($search == FALSE && $search3 == FALSE){
    echo "error";
}elseif($search1 == FALSE && $search2 == FALSE){
    echo "error";
}
```